# How can write a formula in an excel 2010 cell that returns an answer based on 3 different conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get my invoice to autofill a cell when I pick a category from a combobox and then fill in a number in another cell. If the category is Residential, Duplex or Multi-Family the cost is the value entered into B28xthe value of the constant in F28 and this does work.

If I pick Deck I need it to use the same formula unless the Product is less than 60 in which case it should enter 60 as a minimum which does happen.

It's when I need it to return a value greater than 60 which would mean B28 is >400 that the problem arises. The value won't go over 60.

N41 is kind of a holding cell for the value for Deck. When the combobox is empty the formula returns false which I don't want to show in the cell.

Here is my formula

```
=IF(I13="Residential",(B28*F28),IF(I13="Duplex",(B28*F28),IF(I13="Multi- Family",(B28*F28),IF(I13="Deck",IF(N41=0,MAX(0),IF(N41<112.5,MAX(60),IF(N41>=60,MIN(N41),"")))))))
```

Comment: What is the formula in N41?

Comment: @teylyn. The formula in N41 is "=SUM(B28*F28)". I use it to avoid a circular reference when I pick "Deck". The minimum fee for a deck is $60 unless it's part of a house permit then B28*F28 applies. This is my original formula '=IF(I13="Residential",(B28*F28),IF(I13="Duplex",(B28*F28),IF(I13="Multi-Family",(B28*F28),IF(N41=0,MAX(0),IF(N41<112.5,MAX(60),IF(N41>=60,MIN(N41),"")))))))' which works until I need Deck to return >60 which means B28 is greater than 400. I'll try OR as well. Thanks

Comment: I found my problem. I copied the formula from another cell and forgot to make some changes. The 112.5 should have been 400 and no Min. I also don't need N41. And I don't need the "Deck" either. Your comments made me look very carefully and think about exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Min() and Max() are usually used with two arguments, to deliver the smaller or the bigger of two values respectively. You use it with one parameter only, which will return exactly that number. That does not make any sense.

Also, consider using OR() to bundle the first three IFs into one.

It is not clear what the last part of the formula is meant to achieve.

```
=IF(OR(I13="Residential",I13="Duplex",I13="Multi- Family"),B28*F28,IF(I13="Deck",IF(N41=0,0,<here is where it gets unclear>))))
```

Please edit your question and clarify, making sure to post the values and formulas of the contributing cells.